# flowground flow not working as soon as a CBR is added

Tags: integration, ipaas, flowground

I am having this weird issue where as soon as I add a CBR to my flow it suddenly stops working even tough everything seems to be correctly setup.

What I am trying to do is to use the JIRA connector to get data from my JIRA server. Then I am using this data to run a Google Page Speed Insight via an unmanaged connector which totally works. As soon as I am adding a CBR to implement an "if" statement my flow doesn't work anymore. I am using the following expression in my CBR `body.lighthouseResult.audits."uses-optimized-images".score > 0.8`.

Can someone help me out here?

Edit: Screenshot for additional details.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

JSONata doesn't support automatic type conversion. So what it's reading from `score` is of type `string`. Therefore numeric comparison with less, greater or the equal-Operator will fail. Solution: Please convert to type number with the `$number(...score)`-function before you compare.
And please be sure in the future that the Result (the panel below) is solving the comparison to `true` or `false`. Otherwise something went wrong …

Comment: Hey Chris, first of all thank you for your quick answer! Unfortunately this doesn't seem to help. The CBR seems to work fine with the type conversion but it already worked before. What dosen't work is the step after the CBR, where I try to send my data to a REST endpoint. flowground shows me no errors in the configuration but as soon as I am trying to generate a sample it fails with no real description of the error...

Comment: There is a known issue with the CBR regarding the size of the sample data. You can verify that with a flow that looks like this: 1. Webhook 2. CBR 3. HTTP-Reply. First attempt: Use the sample data from your flow in the Webhook. This possibly fails. Second attempt: Use only a small amount of sample data and try again. If this is working you ran into the size-issue.

Comment: Do you have any info when a fix of this bug is to be expected?

Comment: It's on its way. The team is already testing. That's what I've heard.